# A point which is not singular, is regular in Complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is a complex function on domain $D$. Can we say a point which is not singular point, is regular point?
And can anyone prove that the set of singular points of $f$ is a closed set?

Note:
Regular point: A point $x$ in domain $D$ (a subset of Complex field) is said to be regular point if there exsists an open disc around $x$ at which $f$ is throughout differentiable.

Singular point: A point $x$ is said to be singular point if it is a limit point of set of regular points but is not regular itself. Note that a singular point may/maynot belong to the domain, but is a limit point of domain.

If any one can help please? Thanks

Comment: How do you define “singular point” and “regular point”?

Comment: Check question again sir.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to the first part of my question.
E.g., f(z) =  x-iy. No singular point.
Also no regular point.
But domain is whole Complex Field. Hence a point which is not singular, may not be regular.
But I still need proof of second part?